# PHP + MYSQL: select/update/insert from(into) many tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having many tables (shall we call them `tableN`) with fields: `id`, `valueN`. Assume that we have array `(value1 => 'val1', value2 => 'val2', value10 => 'val10')`, what is the way to insert values into `table1`, `table2` and `table10` (I mean something better then doing 3 requests to DB). What is the simpliest way to update values in tables from row (of cause if we know `id`). And finally what is the most elegant way to get all values with `id=ID` from tables (`JOIN` ?).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to write 3 seperate insert statements into the three tables.  That is the way to do it.

If required wrap them in a transaction.

Comment: Well I'm new to this stuff. Are you suggesting doing `mysql_query` 3 times? That will cause 3 request to db? Am I right? What about selecting?

Comment: That's right, execute 3 statements.  Modern databases are blindingly fast.  Don't worry about multiple statements until you find yourself having to execute 100's in a single request.

Comment: You can use a single statement for Selecting, but only when the data is related. If its unrelated simply call mysql_query for each set of data.